# Preview Stretches horizontally on Front using Camera2 Android API

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am porting my application to the Camera2 API. For the preview I am using Textureview to show my preview in square format.

I am using the logic below to scale my camera preview - which works fine on the old camera API - and scale the preview without stretching in portrait mode. But this logic doesn't work on Samsung S4 using the Camera2 API on the front camera. On the rear camera it works fine, which is a bit strange.

I have tried the same code on a Nexus 5x and it works fine on both cameras. Did anyone have the same problem or knows how to solve this problem?

```
public void updateTextureViewSize(int viewWidth, int viewHeight, int previewWidth, int previewHeight, AutoFitTextureView textureView) {

    int scaledHeight;
    int scaledWidth;
    float scaleX = 1.0f;
    float scaleY = 1.0f;
    float ratioCameraPreview = (float) previewHeight / previewWidth;
    float ratioTextureView = viewWidth / viewHeight;

    if (ratioCameraPreview > ratioTextureView) {
        scaledWidth = viewWidth;
        float result = (float) previewHeight / previewWidth;
        result = result * (float) viewWidth;
        scaledHeight = (int) result;
        scaleX = 1;
        scaleY = (float) scaledHeight / scaledWidth;
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, viewWidth / 2, viewWidth / 2);
    textureView.setTransform(matrix);
}
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: I am not sure this is still relevant, but to solve this puzzle, you must disclose the sizes that come as input to **updateTextureViewSize()**. Note that **ratioTextureView** is rounded, unlike **ratioCameraPreview**. Also, **if (ratioTextureView > ratioCameraPreview)**, no scaling will be applied at all.